# Using base-2 numbers: $(1010001)_{2}/(11)_{2}=?$

Tags: computer-science, arithmetic

I wanna solve this simple equation using base-2 number system.

$(1010001)_{2}/(11)_{2}=?$

I can't remember how to do that, normally I would start with $101/11$ but what should I do this base-2 numbers?

Sorry if this question might be silly.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using long division:

```
1010001 / 11
-11||||  | 11011
 --||||
 100|||
 -11|||
  --|||
  0100|
   -11|
    --|
     11
    -11
     --
      0
```

Comment: Is 110011 supposed to be your answer? If so, it's wrong.

Comment: Stray 0 I think

Comment: @TonyK fixed the stray 0

Answer (score 2):

In binary $10-1=1$.

Thus $101-11=10$. This first digit is $1$.

Next $100-11=1$. The second digit is $1$.

$10-0=10$. The next digit is $0$.

$100-11=1$. The next digit is $1$.

Finally $11-11=0$ the last digit is $1$.

Hence
$$(1010001)_{2}/(11)_{2}=11011_{2} \,.$$